# Is it possible to use Settings App to store preferences from external sensors like the Nike+iPod App?

Tags: ios, settings, nsuserdefaults, sensors

Perhaps it is a silly question but I want to be sure about it.

I am developing an app which uses a pulsometer and I am interested in letting the user set the pulsometer which is going to be used in the app (each pulsometer has an unique ID).
As the pulsometer identifier is something that will be hardlyever changed (but it could be changed) Settings App would be the right place to manage that info.

I know I can use NSUserDefaults in a dictionary way to store values, but I don't want the user manually write the identifier code of the sensor in the Settings App. I want to detect the sensor from the app. I know how do that in my App, but is there any way to do it in the Settings App? 
I think it is not possible because it requires including code for executing in the Settings App, but I don't know if it is a way to do it ("linking" the userdefaults with that code or something like that).

For example, the Nike + iPod App lets you detect the sensor in the way I want in the Settings App.

Can anybody confirm that it is not possible (of course, without being Nike and making an agreement with Apple to have the option included in Settings App XD)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up options for your own app "Settings" pane by using display options based on the pulsometer as soon as you startup your application. Your app would have to detect it when running (and determine the range/steps). After that, the user could change a pulldown/stepper in the settings pane from your app. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Ok. So, do you confirm me I can't do the same thing using the Settings App, don't you? I mean: At best, in the Settings App the user could choose the sensor to use between the sensors which previously had been detected in my App (if I store in my App the sensor identifiers in NSUserDefaults). It is impossible to detect the sensor in SettingsApp like it is done in the SettingsApp pane for Nike+ Is that correct?

Comment: So far as I know, you don't code up a Settings pane. You cause it to appear by working with the Settings.bundle/Root.plist then add an array by the `PreferencesSpecifiers` key, then individual settings with `PSToggleSwitchSpecifier` and the like, but I suspect you already know this.